# Infinite dimensional vector spaces revisited

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I want to understand if the following two statements are equivalent:

> No finite subset of $V$, a vector space, spans $V$, and
>
> $V$ has an infinite subset which is linearly independent.

To my understanding they are equivalent(?) ways of stating what an infinite dimensional vector space means. How can one go about proving the equivalence?

Comment: Are you aware of the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) for vector spaces?

Comment: $\Leftarrow$ is obvious: no finite subset can span a infinite linearly independent set. $\Rightarrow$: you have to construct an infinite linearly independent sequence by induction.